# KeyError: 'IDENTITY_ENDPOINT' error in Azure environment

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, azure-managed-identity

I had deployed my application in the Azure Linux environment.

I followed the official python example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=python

```
import os
import requests

identity_endpoint = os.environ["IDENTITY_ENDPOINT"]
identity_header = os.environ["IDENTITY_HEADER"]

def get_bearer_token(resource_uri):
    token_auth_uri = f"{identity_endpoint}?resource={resource_uri}&api-version=2019-08-01"
    head_msi = {'X-IDENTITY-HEADER':identity_header}

    resp = requests.get(token_auth_uri, headers=head_msi)
    access_token = resp.json()['access_token']

    return access_token
```

Why I am getting `KeyError: 'IDENTITY_ENDPOINT'` error? Any configuration I need to do extra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might not have completed a step from the link you provided. Those environment variables get added when you add a Managed Identity to the app in Azure.

The link provides a number of ways to add the identity but for simplicity now, just work with a system assigned identity.

So, for the App Service you made in the Azure Portal, under Identity, check you have that set to `On`:

[image: Adding a system identity]

To confirm that this has created the 2 environment variables we expect, again, in the Portal for your App Service, go to an SSH session (this is in place of the old Console option).

[image: SSH]

In the shell, type `printenv` to see all the environment variables set. Look for the 2 that your app is currently failing to find:

[image: Identity env vars]

If they're missing let me know and at least we'll be better placed to dig further.

Comment: It worked, now the error is gone. But database is not connecting, my SQL server configured with MSI. Anything needs to add in sql server for connect database?

Comment: Probably need to know more about how you're doing it in code - might need to post a separate question. But assuming that's all good, you might just need to add the app as a user on the database:

```
CREATE USER {app_service_name} FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER {app_service_name}
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER {app_service_name}
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER {app_service_name}
```

Replacing {app_service_name} with the name of your app service that is trying to connect to the database. You can find this in the Portal.